# How to check if a column exists in a table with python pyodbc?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyodbc

I am adding the columns to sql table dynamically and the problem I faced is to check whether the column exists or not.

Code I used:

```
 table_name = "mytable.name"
    columns = [
    {
    "field": "name",
    "data_type": "varchar",
    "length": "50"
    },
    {
    "field": "register",
     "data_type": "int"
    }
    ]
for col in columns:
if not cursor.tables(table=table_name, tableType='TABLE').fetchone():
   do some process
else:
   do some process
```

The problem here is I also need to check the if the column exists or not. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simpler as follows:

```
column_check = ("SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name  = {} and column_name = {}").format(your_table, your_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Column information can be read from `information_schema`.

```
sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = \'{}\' and column_name = \'{}\''.format(table_name, column_name)
cursor.execute(sql)
if cursor.fetchone()[0] > 0:
    # Exists
```

If you have multiple databases, they are all in `information_schema`. So you have to include `table_schema` to target the correct database.

```
sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=\'{}\' and table_name = \'{}\' and column_name = \'{}\''.format(schema_name, table_name, key)
```